# Data not getting inserted into Timestream table when timestamp is passed via IoT core rule (via SQL time_to_epoch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

Assuming sensor sends data like this:

```
{"timestamp": "2020-11-11 08:27:19", "temperature": 90, "device": "device1"}
```

1. Create an IoT core rule to send data to Timestream db table.
2. Rule SQL: `SELECT device, temperature, time_to_epoch(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as fn_ts FROM 'topic'`
3. Dimension: `device`

   value: `${device}`
4. Timestamp: `${fn_ts}`

   unit: `MILLISECONDS`

This data does not reach Timestream db. However if I remove the Timestamp fields that were set in step 4 then the data reaches the Timestream db. **What can be the issue?**

Surprisingly - if I republish the output of step 2 to a new topic and create a rule to send the msg from that topic into Timestream db with same config as step 3 and step 4 above then the data goes in the Timestream db.

Also, if the original msg was `{"fn_ts": 1605083835000, "temperature": 90, "device": "device1"}` and I had a rule to send data to Timestream db with same step 3 and step 4 then the data reaches Timestream table.

Answer (score 1):

I just wasted 2 days to play around IoT Rule direct Injestion to the Timestream. I can only confirm that it is as buggy as it seems since the beginning. The only way to use custom timestamp is by doing the workaround you proposed, e.g transforming a payload in a separate rule and redirecting to another IoT topic. Because for some reason, the injestion action does not see fields from the SQL resulting JSON, and I can cleary diagnose it because I attached a CloudWatch action to see every payload I tried to make with SQL.

---

But there is another big problem. When you finally manage to injest data into the table, you will find EVERY single payload field as a separate measure field in the table, even timestamp itself AND all the fields you marked already as dimensoins. That is holerious. After l wasted so much time I still need to proceed using custom lambda to avoid all those messy measures in the table.

Answer (score 0):

With AWS IoT Rules, when you use substitution templates that reference an alias defined in the AS clause of your SQL it will not work as intended.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-substitution-templates.html):

> Because an expression in a substitution template is evaluated separately from the "SELECT ..." statement, you cannot reference an alias created using the AS clause. You can reference only information present in the original payload, functions, and operators.

So with your payload:

```
{"timestamp": "2020-11-11 08:27:19", "temperature": 90, "device": "device1"}
```

If you change your SQL to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 'topic'
```

You will still be able to set your dimension and device as before, but you can set your timestamp like so:

${time_to_epoch(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}

This will use your timestamp to call the time_to_epoch function and use the resulting value as your timestamp within time stream.